# Voltage control tri-phase current circuit at 10 kHz frequency

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, switches, current-source, voltage-measurement

[image]

This is my circuit that use to control tri-phase current (tri-phase is positive, zero and negative).

This circuit include two voltage control current by first will release positive current at the top of R2 and R4 to down of them and
second will release negative current opposite of first direction.

Device that is used to change direction is ''TS5A3159'' from datasheet it can handle 10 kHz frequency.

Vq,VontrolCurrentPos,VontrolCurrentNeg is Digital signal to control switch(TS5A3159) and control current flow through switch (TS5A3159). This is wave from of that

[image]

Shift12left control positive current
Shift12right control negative current

My problem is when take supply on this circuit and measurement voltage drop at load (R2) it is not sharp tri-phase (positive, zero and negative) voltage see fig below:

[image]

This is wave from at pin2 and 6 of TL082 to check that V drop at RS1 and RS2 pull current correctly:

[image]

This is wave from at top and bottom of load (R2). It is look like not sharp and much error clearly when use measurement circuit to look different voltage (Vx-Vy).

[image]

Since I use RS 10 kΩ, vcontol 1 V, 10kHz frequency I should get current 0.1 mA 10 kHz frequency it correct from fig before but why measure voltage drop at load it is not sharp.
Since R load is 1 kΩ, current is 0.1 mA colatge drop at load should be 0.1 V or 100 mV.
It closely correct I see +/- 100 mV but it is not sharp to see 0 V between +/- 100mV.

I use this circuit to measurement Vdrop at Rload:

[image]

Rgain=R2=20 kΩ
R1=R3=10 kΩ

This measurement circuit can measure Vq correcly.

All of this circuit test on breadboard like this:

[image]

I think this problem can decrease if I test this circuit on PCB or stripboard but I need to ask someone about this problem before.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a datasheet for the components. Your ICs are SPDT multiplexers https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Texas%20Instruments%20PDFs/TS5A3159A_Jan2018_DS.pdf. I don't see any capacitors on the schematic or the breadboard. You'll probably see better results if you put 100 nF bypass capacitors on the ICs and a larger capacitor on the power supply. I see one large electrolytic but can't tell how it's connected.

Comment: this "put 100 nF bypass capacitors on the ICs " .Waht do you means pin on ic ?

Comment: Pins 4 and 8 on U1, and V+ to GND on U2 and U3.

Comment: OK i understand on U1 but on U2 ,U3(actually U4) example at pin NO  5V is equl pin V+ 5V on U4 which It's come from voltage divider such as voltage from power supply 10V I divider by 2 resister 2k ohms serie. I use 5V from that point divider .If i put 100 nF bypass capacitors .Will it effect anything to wrong ?

Comment: You don't show a voltage divider for the +5 V supply. A capacitor might be very important there. But it's hard to analyze something that is not revealed on the schematic.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I fixed it . Is there need to use 5V from power supply ?? or It can not use 5V from divider .

Comment: Your 2 kohm voltage divider to get 5 V is not going to work. You need a 5 V voltage regulator with capacitors on both input and output as well as decoupling on every IC.

Comment: _"tri-phase is positive, zero and negative"_ Where did you get this from? Are you referring to a three level inverter?

Comment: winny tri-phase voltage drop at Rload from first control current (+100mV and 0mV)
second control current (0mV and -100mV)

Comment: So a two quadrant inverter?

Comment: No. Vshift12left  will set RS1 to pull one direction current and Vshift12right  will set RS2 to pull opposite direction current.